# Data structure for a matrix containing many zeroes?

Tags: c++, performance, memory, matrix, data-structures

In C++, I have to save in the RAM a very large square matrix that is made of about 90% (true frequency of zeroes depend upon the user input) of zeroes. It would be a waste of RAM to allocate memory for all these zeroes.

How could one make a class that uses little RAM and is convenient to reach an element with something like `instance.getElement(row,column)` into this big matrix?

Comment: The term you’re looking for is “sparse matrix”. There are many data structures to choose from. For simple use cases, a map from (row, column) pairs to values isn’t a bad representation.

Comment: You should check out the Armadillo C++ library and its sparse matrix class (http://arma.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to go. But first thing to consider is that you'll get a good hit in performance for doing this as accessing elements will become more complicated. Second, you'll be unable to use famous libraries like LAPACK, because as far as I know, they don't provide any interface for such complicated data structures. So, every time you want to do some Mathematical operation, you'll have to either decompress your matrix and flatten it, or you'll have to redevelop the code that does the operation you want to do, which is not really an easy thing to do. The people that did LAPACK did research that for years.

What I'm saying is: Consider the consequences before doing this.

Now after mentioning the consequences, I can mention a method off the top of my head.

1. imagine your matrix as a flat array, ordered in [column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) (hence column after column in memory), contiguous in memory.
2. Now this matrix is a list that has many zeros. Your question is: How do we eliminate these zeros?

Well there are many ways to go, and each method will have different computational complexity that depends on your application, let me mention some of the methods:

- You could use a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), where every element can be `std::pair`, containing the value of the current matrix element, and the index of the next available element.
- You could use a linked list, and you could use the way some compression software works, and count how many zeroes you have before every element, and store it in a container for every element.

You see, there are really many ways to go... I could think and guess another few. But ask yourself: What's the computational complexity you're looking for?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Eigen library to do sparse matrix manipulations. Here's the link: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html

Eigen is a high-performance linear algebra library. The sparse matrix is stored like a 2D linked list (or should I say network). Every nonzero entry has two pointers, one pointing to the next nonzero entry of the same row, and the other pointing to the next nonzero entry of the same column. Matrix product and many other linear albegra manipulations based on iteratively multiplying the sparse matrix onto a vector can be done efficiently in the 2D linked list representation.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to modify your matrix dynamically, then you can use the CRS format (Compressed Row Storage), see [1]. It is much more compact than the linked-list suggested in the other answer, that needs additional space to store the pointers. It is implemented in many software libraries, such as SuiteSparse [2] and Eigen [3] cited in another answer, and in my own OpenNL library [4]. If you need to dynamically insert elements in the matrix, then it is more complicated. I often use an array of dynamically allocated rows (one per I). Each row stores J-value pairs. This structure is also implemented in OpenNL [4].

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

[2] http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html

[3] http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/

[4] http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/nl_8h.html

Answer (score -3):

Guess you could make a class that saves everything in a map. So if you request a non existing element it return 0 otherwise it return the element

```
#include <map>

using namespace std;

#define ROW_LENGTH 10;

map<int, int> entries = map<int, int>();

int getElement(int row, int column) {
  int key = column * ROW_LENGTH + row;

  if (entries.find(key) == entries.end()) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return entries[key];
  }
}
void setElement(int row, int column, int value) {
  int key = column * ROW_LENGTH + row;

  entries[key] = value;
}
```

Comment: when you use [] to access an unknown map key, the map creates and default initializes an entry for that key. As a result, the map grows as you access the spares matrix, eventually being much larger than had you used a standard array.

Comment: therefor i checkt if a key already exist with `if (entries.find(key) == entries.end())`. So the map only grows if you are realy inserting new elements. Otherwise i understood something completly wrong :/

Comment: You have me there. Two tweaks: `map<pair<int,int>,int>` to go 2D and cache the result of `entries.find()` and use it instead of performing the same lookup again with `entries[]`.

Comment: Ok saving return of `entries.find()` I totally agree. Using `pair<int, int>` instead of `int` would be easier if you have some kind of size changing structure otherwise using column * rowSize + row should be sufficient I guess.  And I can currently not check if `pair<, >` is using a little bit more memory  but I think so XD

Comment: Ok forget what i sad about memory it's more.  Just rethought it XD

Comment: This would result in terrible performances for several reasons: when looking-up an entry, std::map adds a log(n) complexity. Another problem is that it uses RB trees with dynamically allocated nodes, that fragment memory. High performance sparse linear algebra uses much simpler data structures (contiguously allocated in memory).